Is David Deutsch correct in stating that the Copenhagen interpretation of QM has few defenders left?
In his site here, he says

Confusion, obfuscation or inconsistency, including non-dynamical ‘wave function collapse’ theories, the ‘Copenhagen interpretation’ (which is in some sense still the canonical view of quantum theory, though it has few actual defenders left), and much of the informal discussion of the meaning of quantum theory that appears in textbooks. To these we must add countless concoctions of pseudo-science and mysticism to which this whole regrettable and unnecessary controversy has inevitably opened the door.

He also makes the more bold claim that any instrumentalist interpretations of QM are not really interpretations but rather a way to simply ignore what the evidence of QM tells them about reality,

In addition to these disputes over rival conceptions of reality, there have sometimes been disputes between a realistic theory and an instrumentalist doctrine that denies that the theory describes reality. For example the Inquisition in Galileo’s time permitted advocacy of the heliocentric theory if it was regarded purely as a means of predicting astronomical observations, but not if it was interpreted as a factual theory of where and what the planets and the Earth are. Similar instrumentalist doctrines have been applied to quantum theory. What these miscellaneous revisionist views of scientific theories have in common is a loss of philosophical nerve in situations where, as Lockwood puts it, “there are no conservative options”. That is, they are not so much bona fide rival ontologies struggling to be heard, as psychological manoeuvres whose purpose is to blind their defenders to evidence of something unwelcome: the motion of the Earth, the curvature of spacetime, dinosaurs, or other universes.

From the general gist of the article, he seems to be stating that the Copenhagen interpretation is vague and/or inconsistent and doesn’t really tell us much. However, from a poll that was conducted among physicists (although admittedly more than a decade ago), it seems that the interpretation still is shared by the most number of physicists (although still less than 50%).
Is this because it is still the most accepted interpretation or because it is often used as a euphemism for “we don’t really know or care about what’s going on underneath” in physics?
It seems that Sean Carroll expounds a similar view after discussing that poll in his blog,

I’ll go out on a limb to suggest that the results of this poll should be very embarrassing to physicists. Not, I hasten to add, because Copenhagen came in first, although that’s also a perspective I might want to defend (I think Copenhagen is completely ill-defined, and shouldn’t be the favorite anything of any thoughtful person). The embarrassing thing is that we don’t have agreement.


Seems like a better fit for the [physics.se] site. Although something to this effect has already been asked there: Is the Copenhagen interpretation still the most widely accepted position?. But that just references the poll you already mentioned, showing that Copenhagen is the most popular interpretation (but also pointing out that this is a collection of views). (I also see you already asked it there.)

@NotThatGuy I did post there but I think this is partially a philosophical question as well since it’s about interpretations of QM and some of them don’t like talking about the actual implications of their theories!

The 2011 survey, which was of just 33 physicists, showed Deutch was asserting a falsehood.  The 2016 survey, with a larger survey population of 149 participants, likewise showed a plurality for Copenhagen.  https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg23331074-600-physicists-cant-agree-on-what-the-quantum-world-looks-like/#:~:text=There%20was%20no%20consensus%20among,had%20no%20preference%20at%20all.
The more recent and larger survey shows Copenhagen is even more dominant than the 2011 one, as all other options combined only gathered 25% support, vs, the 39% for Copenhagen.
A peculiarity of the 2011 survey, along with its very small sample size is that its percentages sum to significantly more than 100% for the supposedly single preferred interpretation for the survey takers!  These two observations make me at least somewhat suspicious of its results.
Here are the results of the 2016 survey:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00676.pdf

Thank you for the link! Yeah it seems then that he is simply incorrect. The only way he would be correct is if when physicists say Copenhagen, it’s a euphemism for “I haven’t really thought about which interpretation is correct or care about it, but this seems like the default”

@Mikhail -- 39% vs. 6% for Copenhagen vs. "next most popular option" is -- not really a contest.  Coopenhagen remains the near consensus view of physicists.

I wouldn’t call 39% a consensus to be honest. A consensus implies the vast majority of them believe in something and about the same % don’t even prefer an interpretation

Yes, not consensus.  But domination.  Note that other than Bohm, all of these are probabalistic.  Stochiometry is consensus.

I don't believe this is measuring the same thing that Deutsch is talking about. His choice of words "actual defenders" suggests he is talking about experts in QM who are actively arguing for and defending it, not the opinions of a not-particularly-representative sample of "graduate students, Ph.D. students, Ph..D graduates, Professors or Lector Emeriti".

@JackAidley -- if DD were just arguing that Heisenberg, Bohr, and Bell were all dead, as opposed to being both dead and wrong, his claim would be irrelevant, and he could not draw any conclusions of significance.  He is instead arguing that their views are indefensible, by asserting they have no (or at least few) current noteworthy defenders.  The counterargument is that the noisy critics of Copenhagen have demonstrably failed to convince their peers.

I can, as a lay person interested in qm, try to explain some of David Deutsch words, hopefully successfully:
First of all, Copenhagen is taught by default at universities - they teach it as if it's the standard or most obvious interpretation - which means that most physicists who aren't interested in investigating the question of interpretation are possibly naturally predisposed to answer "Copenhagen" by default. If you don't ever bother to think about the question, you'll just say what your teachers and your textbook say.
Secondly, the Copenhagen interpretation is also sometimes called "shut up and calculate" - shut up and calculate is not an interpretation, it's an anti interpretation. It's saying "we don't need to interpret what's happening, we just need to use the models to make useful predictions". That's fine as an opinion, but it's not an interpretation, it doesn't give us an idea of what's really going on with quantum experiments, which is exactly what quantum interpretations are supposed to do - they're supposed to tell us what's really going on. Not all Copenhagen interpretationsists will say that it's just shut up and calculate, some of them will say it's a real interpretation with real consequences for how the world works and why quantum mechanics gives good predictions.
David Deutsch is a physicist and he speaks to a lot of physicists, which means that he may have a deeper understanding of the views of his fellow physicists than can be accurately gathered in a poll. He may, in his experience talking to thousands of other physicists, have learned that one of the above two explanations - or both to some degree - explain why most physicists write down "Copenhagen" when asked for their preferred interpretation. Most of them may choose that because they simply prefer not to think about interpretations at all. It's also possible that he's just wrong, and you should take the poll results at face value.
I don't know if he's correct or not, I haven't spoken with thousands of physicists. Copenhagen seems like a particularly bad choice to me, because it conflicts with Relativity, but what do I know?

Copenhagen doesn’t actually conflict with relativity unless one makes the further assumption that correlations between particles far apart from each other occur because of some FTL influence. The rest of your answer make sense though!

Don't forget that according to DD there must be universes in which every possible interpretation of QM are favoured, so perhaps he is just in the wrong one.

That was honestly hilarious to even imagine but I don’t think that even in many worlds, “every interpretation” is possible. It just implies that every possible outcome (and not interpretation) in QM gets realized

The discussions I have seen on QM vs. relativity primarily assume that Relativity is what is wrong.  That was what Bell showed with his inequality.  And the multiple subsequent tests that show coupling is real confirm that.  Also, I don't think any of these interpretations are compatible with relativity.

@Dcleve most physicists do not think relativity is wrong. Bell’s tests show non local correlations that can’t be explained with local hidden variables that produce constant and definite states in each entangled particle since creation but superluminsl signalling isn’t confirmed (although it may be what’s going on)

@Mikhail Bells inequality shows that our world must be either lon-local (violates the light speed limit of GR) or non-real (there is a reality that is independent of the observer).  Most physicists have gone for non-local, putting them in direct conflict with GR.  Here is a quote from this link:  https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/quantum-nonlocality-and-reality-50-years-of-bells-theorem/

"Quantum mechanics is non-local, in the same way as Newtonian gravity, in the sense that there exist interactions between events in space-time that can only be connected by signals moving faster than the speed of light. However, unlike Newtonian gravity, the non-locality of quantum mechanics is not an artifact of the provisional nature of the theory. Rather, any possible alternative for quantum mechanics must be non-local, at least if it is to agree with certain predictions of quantum mechanics. Since these predictions seem to be well confirmed by experiments, the non-locality is inescapable.

And this paper cites Bells' disproof of locality:  In a generalized variant of his theorem, Bell ventures to show that locality in one form or another should be rejected regardless of the issue of hidden variables (Bell 1975, 1981).  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41470-019-00046-z   Note that if a theory violates locality, by definition it violates GR.  And so far, every test of Bell has come out in his favor, to the point that he is revered even more so than the founders of QM.

@Dcleve I am sorry but you are misinformed and equivocating the term locality. In the sense that correlations occur between particles far apart from each other, yes, all physicists agree on this. In the sense that you can actually signal something at super luminal speeds, then no, they do not. Quantum field theory was designed to be in line with relativity. I do agree that Bell experiments could show non local causes (and I am a bit inclined to think that or think of some other cause) but we don’t have any direct evidence

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I learn from the answer of @Dcleve that Deutsch is not correct with his estimate about the degree of acceptance of the Copenhagen interpretation of Quantum Mechanics (QM).
But the percentage of supporters of one or the other interpretation is not the most interesting aspect of this problem of the century. Much more important is to understand where and how the many interpretations differ from each other. And on which formal mathematical basis they rely.
Because the present site is a philosophical and not a physics platform, it may be helpful to recall the key idea and the mathematical basis of each interpretation. A former post on this site recommended the following paper Nine formulations of quantum mechanics.
The paper gives an ecellent overview over these nine formulations of QM and the mathematical key concepts of each. It also indicates further references. The paper has a pedagogical aim, and addresses non-specialists.
Note. I changed the term "interpretation" to "formulation" in my last section due to the current comments. Confer also the corresponding remark on p. 288 of the linked paper.

Thanks for the reference.  I am a very non-specialist.  I had a significant question about the paper, however.  "Formulations" and also "interpretations" strongly imply that these alternatives will give identical answers, and are just different computational methodologies.  Einstein disagrees, and set out to find ways to distinguish hidden variables from Coopenhagen.  I. E. they were different theories.  This also appears to be the case with Bohm, see: https://settheory.net/Bohm, and the recognition that Bohmian Mechanics is a competing theory.

Everett, at least, makes different ontological predictions about the number of universes we inhabit (potentially one, for Copenhagen, effectively infinite for Everett), and different  predictions is generally taken as the criteria of being a different theory.  Have the differences or not in the predictions of these multiple formulations been explored?  And why are the ones with differing predictions not just called different theories?

@Dcleve None of them have different predictions and so they’re considered empirically equivalent. Of course they have different ontologies but how would you test them? I believe Bohmian mechanics has a few different predictions in principle but none that can be done right now

@Mikhail -- The different formulations often give the same, or at least indistinguishable predictions.  But Einstein, admirably, put significant effort into trying to sort out the cases where his preferred hidden variables "formulation/interpretation" actually made different predictions, and could therefore be tested against Copenhagen.  Critics of Bohm have been putting that work in as well, leading to a trend of negative hints against Bohm. So for those two at least, which initially were claimed just to be different formulations, they are actually different theories, and are being falsified.

It is possible that some of the differences ARE just "formulation" or "interpretation" differences. But given that the different "interpretations" make different ontological assumptions, my expectation is that they will, when carefully examined, mostly be shown to be different theories as well.  I was hoping Jo had some more background on any such investigations which might apply to anything besides Bohm.

@Dcleve Concerning the two terms "formulation" and "interpretation" the paper from my link makes a comment at page 288, left column at the end. See also the right column on top the reference 3 to the seminal paper of Heisenberg.

Interesting,  Reference 3 considers all the interpretations to be differing theories (page 1, middle column, top paragraph).  I had thought, per my understanding of English, that "formulations" to be the term for a stronger difference, and "theories" to be stronger yet, with "interpretations" being irrelevant differences.  OK, I will use their definitions here.  I disagree with the reference -- QM DOES need a theory, if it is to be predictively useful.  Hence the differing interpretations, and sorting between them is a necessary activity for physics.

@Dcleve QM is one of the theories with the best predictions, and its expansion as Quantum Electrodynamics (QED) is the theory with the most precise predictions in this domain. - Prediction and interpretation are not necessarily linked.

@JoWehler -- I have encountered this shift from QM to QED in discussions, but the subtleties of what makes QED different from QM have eluded me so far.  And as far as I could tell, the differing "interpretations" identified on, for instance , the Wikipedia page on QM seem like they would still apply to QED.  There is enough confusion among us non-specialists on what the philosophic consequences of QM are, that I have not changed my reference label as that seems likely to just multiply the confusion.  Is this a difference I should pay more attention to?

@Dcleve QED is the first quantum field theory (QFT) which incorporates particle creation and particle annihilation. It takes the concept of a field as its basic concept – like electrodynamics - not the particle concept. All difficulties to interpret QM carry over to QED and QFT. (1/2)

@Dcleve An often quoted statement of Feynman: Nobody understands QM. And that’s not meant as one of his many yokes. I do not expect that the solution of the problem comes from philosophers because they are not the experts on this difficult field. There are few contemporary working physicists who show an interest in the interpretation of QM. One of them is Carlo Rovelli. (2/2)

@Dcleve in physics two formalisms would differ only in their mathematical treatment, with each using a treatment that was mathematically equivalent to the other but expressed in a different way. Famously, Heisenberg developed 'matrix mechanics' and Shrodinger 'wave mechanics' which appeared to be different theories at the time, but were later shown to be mathematically equivalent.

@Dcleve I think you are right to question how the word 'interpretation' is used.

Upon what evidence would you expect an answer to be based? Who would qualify as a bona fide 'defender'? Would you confine the role of the defence of Copenhagen to physicists specialising in quantum theory and its applications? Would you want to canvass all of them, or would you accept another poll? How would you ensure the poll was representative and not overly populated with the views of people such as DD?
I think that where DD is right is in saying that the Copenhagen description is full of unsatisfactory conceptual holes. Where he is wrong, in my opinion, is that he is biased towards a particular way of looking at the meaning of QM.
I doubt you will find 'defenders' of Copenhagen in the sense of there being people who will fanatically promote it in the same way as some people promote competing interpretations. What you will find are many practicing physicists who are comfortable with Copenhagen, because it was the basis upon which they learned QM, who understand its conceptual limitations, but are skeptical about paying too much attention to a mutually inconsistent array of competing ideas based on metaphysical speculations which don't make a difference to their calculations anyway.
If a rival interpretation emerges which allows calculations that are simpler or in better agreement with experiment, I'm sure Copenhagen will get binned in favour of it. However, nonsense such as 'I am drinking tea and simultaneously drinking coffee' is not going to be the basis upon which serious physicists will flock to another interpretation.

Intuitively, I don’t see how it is any more or less nonsensical than reality being indefinite (Copenhagen) or non local influences (deterministic theories) or non local correlations occurring without a mechanism at all in entanglement. One of them has to be right! (I lean towards the second but would have to think about it further)

Yes please do think about it further! The tea/coffee business is bona fide nonsense.

Carlo Rovelli has an update of the Copenhagen Interpretation that plugs some of its gaps called Relational QM. This supposes that it is not just a classical measuring apparatus which is an observer, but essentially any interaction between quantum systems. This has its defenders.

Did you ever study whether Rovelli's Loop Quantum Gravity depends on his Relational QM interpretation?

@Jo Wehler: No, I haven't studied it. But he mentions it in his textbook on the subject.

Funny, I thought that was obvious since instruments and organic observers alike (there is no principal difference) are just (albeit complex) quantum systems. The implication is, of course, a propagating superposition which should please the Dalai Lama because everything is connected to everything.
